# Less secure apps for Gmail and Google Apps

Tags: google-workspace

I have opened a Google Apps account and I'd like to turn on the "Access for less secure apps" option. The problem is when I go to this page https://www.google.com/settings/u/0/security/lesssecureapps I just get "This setting is managed by your domain administrator." message only. What can I do about it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't have the right to turn it on yourself. You can ask your Google Apps administrator to allow users to turn it on, they can do this at

`https://admin.google.com/EXAMPLE.COM/AdminHome#ServiceSettings/notab=1&service=securitysetting&subtab=lesssecureappsaccess`

Or from https://admin.google.com/, go to Basic Settings => Security => Less secure apps

Comment: Note: It may take a maximum of 24hrs to reflect this change on G Suites IDs according to Google.